# How to structure intermediate component

Tags: vue.js

i would love to get some input on a problem i stumbled upon recently.
Say, i have a `Container` component for layout and interaction, that will be placed between the parent and the child component. The content (=the child) will be a dynamic component, that will give data to the `Container`, but also needs data from the parent. How would i structure this to achieve a nice and easy data-flow?

My current setup looks something like this, where i

```
<Parent>
  <Container :title="titleFromChild">
    <DynamicChild :dataProps="dataFromParent" />
  </Container>
</Parent>
```

However, this feels wrong, since it is getting quite difficult to get data back out of the `Child` and into the `Container`. It feels like i have the wrong setup and something like the following would be better.

```
<Parent>
  <Container 
    :title="titleFromChild"
    :component="dynamicChild"
    :dataProps="dataFromParent"
  />
</Parent>
```

Anyone had this problem and can give me some insights?

Answer (score 1):

You should try [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#parent) from the official Vue API references.

Answer (score 0):

Data from child will be received in parent by event call, so you can attach a handler with this event

```
<Parent>
  <Container :title="titleFromChild">
    <DynamicChild :dataProps="dataFromParent" data-from-child-event="dataFromChildHandler" />
  </Container>
</Parent>



new Vue({

methods: dataFromChildHandler(dataFromChild){
  console.log(dataFromChild);
}
});
```